# How to fix the unknown number on tithing

Tags: c++

It enters fine once I compile it, however, when I get the results from my input, I happened to notice that in actual budget tithe, it doesn't give me the number that I inputted.

*This is What I have tried so far :*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

float getIncome(float income);
float getBudgetLiving(float budgetLiving);
float getActualLiving(float actualLiving);
void display(float income,  float tithing,  float other, float budgetLiving, float actualLiving, float tax);
float getActualOther(float other);
float getActualTithing(float tithing);
float getActualTax(float tax);

float getIncome(float income) {
    cout << "\tYour monthly income: ";
    cin >> income;
    return income;
}

float getBudgetLiving(float budgetLiving) {
    cout << "\tYour Budgeted Living expenses: ";
    cin >> budgetLiving;
    return budgetLiving;
}

float getActualLiving(float actualLiving) {
    cout << "\tYour actual Living expenses: ";
    cin >> actualLiving;
    return actualLiving;
}
```

---

I feel that I have corrected everything that I had wrong, but i feel like my void is the problem.

---

```
void display(float income,  float tithing,  float other, float budgetLiving, float actualLiving, float tax) {

    cout << "\nThe following is a report on your monthly expenses\n";
    cout << "\tItem                  Budget           Actual   \n" <<
        "\t================ =============== =============== \n";

    cout << "\tIncome           $" << setw(11) << income << "    $" <<
        setw(11) << income << endl;

    cout << "\tTaxes            $" << setw(11) << 0.00 << "    $" <<
        setw(11) << tax << endl;

    cout << "\tTithing          $" << setw(11) << 0.00 << "    $" <<
        setw(11) << tithing << endl; //There is an error that I dont undestand what I am doing 

    cout << "\tLiving           $" << setw(11) << budgetLiving << "           $" <<
        setw(11) << actualLiving << endl;

    cout << "\tOther            $" << setw(11) << 0.00 << "    $" <<
        setw(11) << other << endl;

    cout << "\t================ =============== =============== \n";

    cout << "\tDifference       $" << setw(11) << 0.00 << "    $" <<
        setw(11) << tax << endl;

}

float getActualOther(float other) {
    cout << "\tYour actual other expenses: ";
    cin >> other;
    return other;
}

float getActualTithing(float tithing) {
    cout << "\tYour actual tithe offering: ";
    cin >> tithing;
    return tithing;
}

float getActualTax(float tax) {
    cout << "\tYour actual taxes withheld: ";
    cin >> tax;
    return tax;
}

float computeTax(float income) {
    return 0;
}

float computeTithing(float income) {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    cout << "This program keeps track of your monthly budget\n" <<
        "please enter the following:\n";
    float income = getIncome(income);
    float budgetLiving = getBudgetLiving(budgetLiving);
    float actualLiving = getActualLiving(actualLiving);
    float tax = getActualTax(tax);

    float tithing;
    getActualTithing(tithing);

    float other = getActualOther(other);

    display(income, tithing, other, budgetLiving, actualLiving, tax);

    return 0;

}
```

The above Code has commented line where i think the problem is.
Thanks!

Comment: Please show a [mre], what is the input you give, what is the output, what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @NickCoder. I do hope that you did not edit the code in that way. Whoever it did, the code was absolutely unreadable. I reformatted now. And only through reformatting, the bug jumps at your eyes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're rather new in programing and do not yet understand functions, how to pass parameters and how to return values from functions.

The bug can be found easily. It has of course nothing to do with "void" or something. Let's start with that.

```
float tithing;
getActualTithing(tithing);
```

You define the variable "tithing", but you do not initialize it. You do not give it an initial value (you MUST ALWAYS initialize all variables). So the value of the variable is "something". And then, in contrast to your other functions, you do not assign a value to "tithing".

You just call the function "getActualTithing(tithing);" but you do not assign the resulting value to to the tithing variable. Like you did for example  in

```
float actualLiving = getActualLiving(actualLiving);
```

But that is not the main problem. As said, you do not understand functions, parameters and retrun values. You urgently need to read about that.

All you functions follow the same pattern, like in

```
float getActualTax(float tax) {
    cout << "\tYour actual taxes withheld: ";
    cin >> tax;
    return tax;
}
```

For wahtever reason that I do not know, you are passing the variable "tax" by value to your function. This has no meaning and no effect. You are passing by value. So, you will make a copy and then overwrite the value. No effect and no meaning.

Please read about:

- Pass by value
- Pass by reference
- Pass by pointer

Read about functions and return values.

Then revisit you code.

Comment: ,what you are saying is that, there is no point putting an argument on the function because I'm not passing a value?  you assumed right, I am a beginner to programing. :) Also thank you for helping me out understand more.